# Downloading Segoe UI Light into a web app

Tags: css, fonts

How could I possibly get **Segoe UI Light** to work as a font for a Rails 3.2 web application using Sass/ CSS.

I've researched quite a bit and it seems they only offer *Segoe UI Mono* font (a completely different one) [here](http://www.ascendercorp.com/font/segoe-ui/)

I've been using the **@import** method for a few Google Web Fonts in the past, and am wondering how I could possibly do the same with the Segoi UI Light font/ or is there is a different method for downloading/ using it in my app.

Thank you!

Comment: You can't, as you don't own the rights to redistribute it. However, OpenSans is made by the same guy, and is pretty similar and is on Google Web Fonts.

Comment: Sounds good/looks very similar. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an online webfont converter like http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator to convert the ttf font to several web compatible formats.

However, I think, you do not have the rights to distribute Segoe UI in a website, so you may use this only for a none public private project.